# mm-qcamera-daemon wakelock when idle

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, camera, wakelock

My phone will randomly get the mm-qcamera-daemon wakelock. I know how to fix it, a simple reboot and all that, but it pops up when my phone is idle in my pocket. The phone starts to run hot and I can't restart it until it's nearly too late.

I haven't installed many apps that use the camera, and all of them are usually closed by the time I don't use my phone at school or anything. Possible culprits IMO are Lux and Flashlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug with Android 4.4.2 KitKat.  Google is [aware](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60058#c475) of it and are [promising a fix](http://www.droidreport.com/nexus-5-camera-bug-fix-update-google-promises-battery-drain-android-442-will-be-resolved-next-7212) with the next update.

According to the Google Code discussion, simply killing the responsible app is not enough to stop the drain. A reboot is always necessary. Uninstalling the app seems to be the only sure way to avoid having this happen in the first place.

Skype seems to be the most frequent culprit because its background services seem to interface with the camera, triggering Android's bug. It is recommended to temporarily uninstall such apps until Google releases the fix.

Comment: I know, but I thought that was only on a failure to connect to camera error, not just for nothing.

Comment: Apparently it could surface from any prior usage of camera, even by background processes.  Skype is singled out because it has a tendency to "touch" camera while its services are running in the background.

Comment: Hmm. So could killing Skype be a possible solution? I have it installed.

Comment: According to the Google Code discussion, simply killing the responsible app is not enough to stop the drain. A reboot is always necessary. Uninstalling the app seems to be the only sure way to avoid having this happen in the first place.